# Bad protocol version identification ' ' from xx.xx.xx.xx port xx

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, sshd

I've set up my raspberry pi to be able to connect to outside network so i can access it when not there. Now that it's connected to the internet people are what i assume port-scanning it but as it is in an unknown log entry to me i don't exactly know what the meaning of the entries are. such entries are:

`Bad protocol version identification '\003' from 185.156.177.20 port 440`

`Bad protocol version identification 'GET / HTTP/1.0' from 180.76.250.210 port 40756`

`Bad protocol version identification 'GET / HTTP/1.1' from 51.15.191.81 port 39919`

`Bad protocol version identification '' from 198.108.67.48 port 19536`

`Bad protocol version identification 'OPTIONS / RTSP/1.0' from 180.76.250.210 port 40782`

`Bad protocol version identification 'a001 CLOSE' from 107.6.183.226 port 45564`

`Bad protocol version identification 'QUIT' from 107.6.183.226 port 59028`

`Bad protocol version identification '\200.\001' from 107.6.183.226 port 37566`

`Bad protocol version identification '\026\003\001' from 107.6.183.226 port 51182`

these entries come from the localhost sshd[xxxxx].

i don't know what any of these entries mean expect that they come from that ip. whether that is the port they tried connecting from or to is unknown to me too

i've installed ubuntu mate 18.04 on it and these entries are both found in the /var/log/auth.log and systemctl status sshd

Comment: You may want to have a look [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29509/ssh-bad-protocol-version-identification-string-what-is-it).

Comment: that just says that it's standard internet noise, which is understandable but i was more hoping to understand what these attempts where.